# SQL Server(Azure Database- timestamp issue)

Tags: azure-sql-database

i have some databases in azure and when i am running one if---else query I am getting performance issues[running on a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6l6c.jpg) and it's running in a loop.one thing i found that it because of some time stamp.how to stop it going on a loop
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please copy paste insightful error instead of providing a hard to read screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for IF...ELSE statement in T-SQL is:

```
IF Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

Now this `{ sql_statement | statement_block }` is any Transact-SQL statement or statement grouping as defined by using a statement block. **Unless a statement block is used, the IF or ELSE condition can affect the performance of only one Transact-SQL statement.**

So, I recommend you to use the `statement block` properly for better results.

Refer [IF...ELSE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details.